Notification click opens alway a launcher activity
when I click on notification, the tap action always starts an app with launcher activity, even though the app is already running. I tried different flag configurations and whatsoever but nothing helped. Any idea?
Notification:
private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody, String senderID) {
        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        launchIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        launchIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, launchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        String channelId = "PushNotificationChannel"; // Create a unique channel ID
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("Neview")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(messageBody)
                        )
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since Android Oreo (API level 26), notification channels are required.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "PushNotifications",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), notificationBuilder.build());
    }

Manifest:
 <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:name="com.cybertyc.neview_android.MainActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
<activity
            android:name="com.cybertyc.neview_android.SplashScreen.SplashScreen_page"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>




You may write the code like this.

//You need create one service class.

val intent = Intent(context,ThisService::class.java)
intent.putExtra("notify",1)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

//You Builder set the pendingIntent.
Builder().setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

//The ThisService will callback onStartCommand method when click notification.
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

        intent?.let {
            val key = it.extras?.getInt("notify")
            when (key) {
                1 -> {
                    //You operate
                    //#########
                }
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY
    }




i have no onStartCommand method in superclass (using FirebaseMessagingService)

It could be related to the launchMode of your activities in the manifest.
launchMode of your MainActivity is set to singleTask. This launch mode creates a new instance of the activity as the root of a new task, regardless of whether the app is already running or not.
try changing the launchMode of your MainActivity to singleTop. The singleTop launch mode allows the system to reuse the existing instance of the activity if it's already at the top of the task stack.
<activity
    android:name="com.cybertyc.neview_android.MainActivity"
    android:exported="false"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <!-- Intent filter for launcher activity -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

